# Intuition behind conditional independence of two events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, intuition, independence

I am struggling to grasp the intuition behind conditional independence. I would be very thankful if someone can help me with the below problem-

A certain baby cries if and only if she
is hungry, tired, or both. Let C be the event that the baby is crying, H be the event
that she is hungry, and T be the event that she is tired. Let P(C) = c; P(H) = h;
and P(T) = t, where none of c; h; t are equal to 0 or 1. Let H and T be independent.

Are H and T conditionally independent given C? Explain in two ways: algebraically
and with an intuitive explanation in words.

I am able to algebraically solve it and figure that the H & T are not conditionally independent but still struggling with the intuition.

Like I understand being tired(T) or hungry(H) in no way effect the probabilities of each other. Then how does the fact that given baby is crying and tired gives us additional evidence about its hunger status and vice versa?

Comment: There are $2^3=8$ possible combinations of the three events C,H,T and their complements though half of them have probability $0$.  You can then work these out, and thus the conditional probabilities.   For example you can find $P(H \mid C,T)=\frac{P(H,T,C)}{P(T,C)} = \frac{P(H,T,C)}{P(H,T,C)+P(H^c,T,C)}$

Comment: The basic intuition is that if the baby was crying, but you knew she wasn't hungry (say you fed her just a little while ago), then it's much more likely that she is tired.   So, $P(T=1|H=0, C=1) \neq P(T=1|C=0)$. More broadly, the idea is that if a dependent variable is caused by two independent causal variables, then given the value of rhe dependent variable, the causal variables are no longer independent since if one was inactive, the other would have a higher chance of being active than the baseline. Such structures are called colliders in causal inference, googling the term may be useful.

Comment: In the universe where baby is crying knowing that the baby is *not* tired gives information that she is hungry and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

> > **A certain baby cries if and only if she is hungry, tired, or both.** Let C be the event that the baby is crying, H be the event that she is hungry, and T be the event that she is tired. Let P(C) = c; P(H) = h; and P(T) = t, where none of c; h; t are equal to 0 or 1. Let H and T be independent.

Due to the first sentence, crying is the union of hungry and tired.  Two exhaustive events are only independent when one among them covers the entirety.

Intuitively: When at least one happens, then knowing that one *does not happen*, means that the other *must happen*.  Only when one among them is certain under the condition, can the two events be independent.

Mathematically: $C=H\cup T$, so $\mathsf P(H\cap T)=h+t-c$ .  Hence:$$\mathsf P(H\mid H\cup T)=\dfrac{h}{c}\\\mathsf P(H\mid T \cap( H\cup T))=\dfrac{h+t-c}{t}$$

These are only equal when $(c-t)(c-h)=0$, that is that $C=T$ or $C=H$.